# How to get attached file created date, modified date while reading mailbox java though Javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, attachment

How to get attached file created date, modified date while reading mailbox java though Javamail Api?

I've used `Part.getFileName()` but didn't got anything for getting created date of attached file through java.
While using `part.getFileName()` we usually get filename and after that create an instance of file with this file so created date, modified date changes, but I want attached file created date, modified date of that file only.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  That information is not normally included in an email message.